# Saving all items to a firebase collection as individual documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function where a user types in there sitemap and it returns all the links in there sitemap.

How can I then save all of those links in individual documents in a specific collection on Firebase?

See below for the current firebase set function. Erro returns "Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, "

```
const saveAllCrawl = async () => {
     await db.collection('urls').doc('test').set(urls);
}
```

Current map of the array the sitemap crawler returns & Scrap Sitemap function

```
const scrapeSitemap =  async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(sitemapURL)
  const array = await GetSitemapLinks(sitemapURL);
  setURLS(array)
}

{urls && urls.map((user) => (
      <Grid container spacing={0} >
                    <Grid  xs={6} sm={6} md={6}>
                        <li className="user">{user}</li>
                    </Grid>
      </Grid>
))}
    <Button onClick={saveAllCrawl}>Save All To Firebase</Button>
```

Comment: What part of this use-case is giving you problems? If it's interacting with Firestore, I recommend starting here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem, there are many solutions for your problem, such as saving them as a string "url1;url2..." then you can use split convert it again to a url...

Comment: I have updated the question to help understand it a bit better. I want to save the array "URL" into a firebase collection but as individual documents, not just one document with all values in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In document every value is being stored against a key.

Like if there are multiple urls and you want to store each in a separate document so you have to stored them against any key.
Collections: URLS
Document Id : (generated_key)
Document Data :

```
{ "key" : "url_value" }
```

So, as mentioned above for this you have to create a batch in which you assign all queries to a batch and after that set batch.commit().

Now, if you are trying to store them in a list like an array.

```
{
   "urls": [
   "url_one",
   "url_one"
   ]
}
```

So, first create an object and assigned all string values to key and then set that to a document.